# Solve $2A{\frac{1-\sqrt{w}}{\log{w}}}=1$ in terms of Lambert W function.

Tags: lambert-w

I have tried it in this way: $$2A(1-\sqrt{w})=\log{w}$$ $$w\exp(2A\sqrt{w})=\exp{2A}$$ $$A^2w\exp(2A\sqrt{w})=(A\exp{A})^2$$ $$A^2w=W^2(A\cdot \exp{A})$$ $$w=A^-2W^2(A\cdot \exp{A})$$
Is this solution right?

Comment: I suppose that life could have been easier if you start defining $y=\sqrt w$.

Comment: Your answer is right, but on the last line, you need to have the "-2" in the exponent. What you get is
$$
w=\left(\frac{W\left(A\mathrm e^A\right)}{A}\right)^2
$$

Comment: This equation has exactly one real solution if $A<0$. How?

Comment: I've added an addednum which shows where the second solution comes from. Not that it matters, because it turns out to be a double solution modulo conjugate branches of the Lambert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full extent of the solutions, follow Claude Leibovici's advice.

Note that if you set $y=w^{1/2}$, then $y^2=w$, but because of the squaring you are going to miss solutions, so you need to set up two equations, one for the positive and one for the negative root of the substitution:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2A(1-y)}{\ln(y^2)}&=1\,\,\,\,(1)\\
\frac{2A(1+y)}{\ln(y^2)}&=1\,\,\,\,(2)
\end{align}$$

After simplifying you get:

$$\begin{align}
y&=\exp(A(1-y))\,\,\,(3)\\
y&=\exp(A(1+y))\,\,\,(4)
\end{align}$$

which now have the visible solutions via the standard Lambert algebraic proccess:

$$
\begin{align}
(3)\implies y&=\frac{W(A\cdot\exp(A))}{A}=1\,\,\,\,\text{(for $A>0$, W is a partial inverse of }z\cdot\exp(z))\,\,\,(5)\\
(4)\implies y&=\frac{W(-A\cdot\exp(A))}{-A}\,\,\,(6)
\end{align}$$

from which upon reversing the substitution $y=w^{1/2}$ you get:

$$\begin{align}
(5)\implies w_1&=1\\
(6)\implies w_2&=\left(\frac{W(-A\cdot\exp(A))}{-A}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

---

$\mathbf{Addendum}$-1

If you are wondering about whether $w_2$ simplifies further, yes, it does and it equals 1, because the numerator of the fraction in the parenthesis equals $-A$ again. For details please refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851989/lambertw-x-wx-cdot-ex-for-x-ge-1-but-not-for-x-lt-1-how-do-i/852439#852439) answer of mine from an older question by Gottfried Helms.

---

$\mathbf{Addendum}$-2 (second root clarification)

I was wrong on my first Addendum concerning the second root. It is true that:

$$W(|A|\exp(|A|)=|A|$$

but this does not apply in this case because the signs are alternating, so:

$$\frac{W(-A\cdot\exp(A))}{-A}$$

$\mathbf{cannot}$ be simplified further.

To conclude, the solutions are $w_1=1$ (for $A>0$), and $w_2=\left(\frac{W(-A\cdot\exp(A))}{-A}\right)^2$ (for $A<0$), as above in (6).

---

$\mathbf{Addendum}$-3 (addressing additional solutions)

It is possible that $w_2$ may be complex for all the branches of $W$. Here's an example with Maple code:

```
W := proc (k, w) options operator, arrow; LambertW(k, w) end proc
sol2 := proc (k, A) options operator, arrow; W(k, -A*exp(A))^2/A^2 end proc
for k from -3 to 3 do evalf(sol2(k, 2)) end do #for A=2
```

outputs:

-49.98644048 - 0.3118949792 I

-15.63286398 - 2.455783917 I

-0.5299074982 - 1.853237059 I

-0.5299074982 + 1.853237059 I

-15.63286398 + 2.455783917 I

-49.98644048 + 0.3118949792 I

-104.0602403 - 3.292630660 I

So, in the case of $A=2$ all solutions $w_2$ are complex. You can check that these are indeed solutions, by substituting back to the original equation.

If you have more questions, comment and I will add more.

---

$\mathbf{Addendum}$-4 (addressing your last comment and correcting a typo)

The curves for the ranges of $W(k,z)$ are exactly:

$$
C_k(y) =
\begin{cases}
-y\cot(y)+yi,  &y\in(2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi) \text{, if $k\ge 0$} \\
-y\cot(y)+yi, &y\in((2k+1)\pi,(2k+2)\pi)\text{, if $k<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

In Maple they can be plotted as:

```
restart;
with(plots):
f:=y->-y*cot(y)+y*I;
p0 := complexplot(f(y), y = 0 .. Pi-.2, scaling = constrained);
p01 := complexplot(f(y), y = -Pi+.2 .. 0, scaling = constrained);
p1 := complexplot(f(y), y = 2*Pi+.5 .. 3*Pi-.5, scaling = constrained);
p12 := complexplot(f(y), y = -3*Pi+.5 .. -2*Pi-.5, scaling = constrained);
p2 := complexplot(f(y), y = 4*Pi+.8 .. 5*Pi-.8, scaling = constrained);
p23 := complexplot(f(y), y = -5*Pi+.8 .. -4*Pi-.8, scaling = constrained);
display(p0, p01, p1, p12, p2, p23);
```

I am just breaking the whole thing into segments and subtracting a bit from the ranges to adjust it for full screen.

Sorry, I don't know MatLab, so I have no idea how you could port this. In Maple they are just plots on the Complex plane.

(Corrected a typo, also. Note that the function is $f(y)=-y\cot(y)+yi$, $\mathbf{not}$ $f(y)=\cot(y)+yi$ as I had on my code).

Comment: How to plot the bounding curves for the ranges of $W(k,z)$ in MATLAB. The code that you have provided in one of your link is for Maple it is not working in MATLAB.

Comment: I've added the Maple code so you can see it. It should be fairly easy to port the plotting code to MatLab. Maybe someone else can help translate the code?

Comment: Is Maple is more convenient than Matlab for this purpose? Why everyone uses Maple instead of Matlab?

Comment: Not really. There isn't much Maple can do that Matlab can't. It certainly can do plots of functions, it's just that I don't know in this case the equivalent of "complexplot" for Matlab.

Comment: I also had a small typo on the code. The function is $f(y)=-y\cot(y)+yi$.

Comment: Note also correction for the second root $w_2$. It does NOT equal 1, so it is a valid root of the initial equation.

Comment: @ ioannis galidakis: What do you mean by only two real branches of the Lambert W function? Can you please explain it? What about rest of the branches aren't they real? Are they complex? Are they don't have any significance in the analysis?

Comment: Whenever one finds solutions via the Lambert, one always has infinitely many, via the other branches of the function, since $W$ is multivalued. So if you wanted to look at all solutions, the answer would be $w_2=[W(k,-A\exp(A)/-A]^2$ and this may give complex solutions as well. Usually branches 0 and -1 give real solutions, so check $w_2=[W(0,-A\exp(A)/-A]^2$ and $w_2=[W(-1,-A\exp(A)/-A]^2$. The other solutions are complex.

Comment: What do you mean by complex solutions that is in the form of $a+ib$ or what? I took $a$ = 2 and then i computed this expression, I got a real number for the principal branch and for the rest i got the answer in terms of $a+ib$. I am not getting what is this real solution and complex solution.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. The "other" solutions are complex, in the form of $a+bi$. Usually one is interested in real solutions, so when we solve via $W$, we omit the ones in the form $a+bi$. In the case of $a=2$, all solutions are complex. I will add an addendum to the answer.

Comment: From stability point of view we have the convention that the principal branch have rightmost root, then if it is in left of the complex plane the system is stable otherwise not. How we can say it? Why it is so? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer your question until you define what you mean by "stability". What definition of "stability" are you using and for what?

Comment: Stability of control systems. To check the stability of systems one has to check the roots of the principal branch because the principal branch have rightmost root in the complex s plane, then if it is in left of the plane then the system is stable otherwise not. My question is that why only the principal branch has rightmost root among infinity number of branches and if it is so how we can prove it?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. If you have an online reference, I can see how it applies. Otherwise, I am not familiar with what you mention, above.

Comment: Solve for $k$, $s=2*W(\frac{\exp(-k/2)}{2})+k$.

Comment: Please post this as a new question on SE. As far as I can see, it has nothing to do with the question in this page.